# How to check duplicate value in textfield with XML data (for unique url)

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, xml-parsing, duplicates

let say I have this **alias-url.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aliases>
 <alias>the-plaza-1</alias>
 <alias>the-subway</alias>
 <alias>metro-mall-1</alias>
 <alias>metro-mall-2</alias>
</aliases>
```

And I have the following textfield input form

```
<input name="place_name" id="place" type="text"/>
<input name="url_alias" id="alias" type="text"/>
```

So, the real deal:
- When I type a place on **input#place**, eg: "**The Subway**", it will synchronously return "**the-subway**" on **input#alias** by the following script:

```
$("#place").keyup(function () {
 var value = $(this).val();
 $("#alias").val(value.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase());
    }).keyup();
```

so it will form a friendly-url pattern.

**my problem is:** how to check the input#alias for duplication in my xml file, so when I type eg: "**The Subway**" it will return "**the-subway-1**" and so "**The Plaza**" becoming **"the-plaza-2"** and "**Metro Mall**" becoming "**metro-mall-3**".

Comment: It is not clear here how you are pulling the data from this XML file.

Comment: I generated the XML from Db. I don't want to get directly intouch with Db so I use XML to perform cross-checking routine.The problem is solved when I type **the subway** then it will return **the-subway-1**, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: What I meant is that is is not clear in your javascript that you are even working with this XML file.  Can you show your code where your keyup function is trying to compare the input entered against the XML data? Because at this point it looks like you are just replacing spaces entered in `#place` with a dash and inserting into `#alias` without any attempt to compare to the XML data.